# PHPStorm: How to use a local mdb Access file with Microsoft Access Driver

Tags: database, ms-access, odbc, phpstorm

Can't seem to find an option in PHPStorm Database to use an .mdb file, is there a plugin or other solution ? Or is possible to make the mdb file accessible by IP:PORT and then have PHPStorm use something compatible to connect ?

Thank you.

Comment: While PHPStorm is an IDE, the PHP language can certainly connect to MS Access via [odbc connection](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php).

Comment: 1) PhpStorm's Database plugin does not support MS Access databases. 2) There is no plugins (which you can see via standard "Plugins" section in Settings) that supports it either. 3) It could work if PhpStorm would support generic ODBC access .. but it does not look like it's the case now.

Comment: No problem using connection with PHP, but would be great to have instant access with the PHPSTORM IDE. Read some things about JET engine, I assume it can create a data-server ... I'll keep looking.

Comment: Found a possible solution at http://www.dbheart.com/oracle/connect_msaccess.html .. but would imply installing Oracle Database and use it as a gateway to the .mdb file.